# Calculate $M_X(1)$ where $Y\sim \operatorname{Gamma}(2,2)$ and $(X\mid Y=y)\sim \operatorname{Pois}(y)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables defined on the same sample space. We know that $Y\sim \operatorname{Gamma}(2,2)$ and $(X\mid Y=y)\sim \operatorname{Pois}(y)$. Find $M_X(1)$.

In the solution they wrote:
$$
M_X(1)=E(e^X)=E(E(e^X\mid Y))=E(e^{-Y(1-e)})=M_Y(e-1)=\left(1-\frac{e-1}{2}\right)^{-2}=50.39
$$
I don't understand how did they move from $E(E(e^X\mid Y))$ to $E(e^{-Y(1-e)})$. Did they miss a step or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It was assumed that you know the moment-generating function of the Poisson distribution.

You have $X\mid Y\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(Y).$ Consequently
\begin{align}
& M_{X\,\mid\,Y}(t) = \operatorname E(e^{tX}\mid Y) = \sum_{x=0}^\infty e^{tx} \Pr(X=x\mid Y) \\[10pt]
= {} & \sum_{x=0}^\infty e^{tx}\cdot \frac{Y^x e^{-Y}}{x!} = \sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{\Big(e^t Y\Big)^x e^{-Y}} {x!} \\[10pt]
= {} & e^{-Y}\sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{(e^t Y)^x}{x!} \\
& \text{ (This is valid since $e^{-Y}$ does not change as $x$ goes from 0 to $\infty$.)} \\[12pt]
= {} & e^{-Y} e^{e^t Y} = e^{Y(e^t-1)}.
\end{align}
As a function of $t,$ that is the moment-generating function of the Poisson distribution with expected value $Y.$

Therefore
$$
\operatorname E(e^X\mid Y) = M_{X\,\mid\,Y}(1) = e^{Y(e^1-1)}.
$$

Comment: So, is it true to say that $M_{X|Y}(t)=E(E(X)|Y)$?

Comment: Why $M_{X|Y}(t)=E(e^{tX}|Y)$?

Comment: @vesii : It's true in the following form: $$ M_X(t) = \operatorname E(e^{tX}) = \operatorname E( \operatorname E( e^{tX}\mid Y)) = \operatorname E( M_{X\,\mid\,Y}(t)). $$

Comment: @abuka123 : The conditional moment-generating function of $X$ given $Y$ is the moment-generating function of the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y. \qquad$